# Image Store into MongoDB with mongoose, Express 4.0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I successfully upload a file to my Nodejs server at `./upload/` with `multer`

```
app.use(multer({ dest : './uploads/',
    rename: function(fieldname, filename){
        return filename + '^' + Date.now(); 
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function(file){
        console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting...');
    }, 
    onFileUploadComplete: function(file){
        console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to ' + file.path);
        done=true;
    }
}));
```

So now, I have to store this image file to Mongodb.

I have been searching on www for finding example suitable for my setting, but I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that each document in MongoDB must be under 16MB, if they are larger then that you use [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) if not you just save the image as binary data. That is described on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2408370). The main point of the example for your use is:

```
// Your schema should be set to something like this
var schema = new Schema({
  img: { data: Buffer }
});

// a is a new model of the schema
a.img.data = fs.readFileSync(imgPath);
a.save(function (err, a) {
```

If you don't want to deal with the file on the file system set multer's `inMemory` setting to `true`. Then use the `buffer` from the `multer` object.

```
app.use(function() {
  var img = multer({ inMemory: true})
  a.img.data = img.buffer;
  a.save(cb);
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I have more questions, How can I get files from db? Looks like, I have to use another ireadFileSync type function. there is any other thing? I'll use your second proposal.

Comment: The gist I linked to shows how that can be done, see lines 45-49.

    A.findById(a, function (err, doc) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.contentType(doc.img.contentType);
      res.send(doc.img.data);
    });

Comment: Thanks Smith, I succeed that Img save from local path to DB, and get Img from DB.

But still isn't work multer using inmemory property.

Comment: To help you further with this I will need to see more of your code and have more details onwhat isn't working.